# MD5 authentication for local users

Tags: postgresql

**PostgreSQL 10.0, Ubuntu 16.04**

I'd like users at localhost to login with password.
For this purpose I moved rule with md5 to the top.

**SHOW hba_file;**

```
postgres=# # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
postgres-# 
postgres-# # IPv4 local connections:
postgres-# host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
postgres-# # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
postgres-# local   all             all                                     peer
postgres-# # IPv6 local connections:
postgres-# host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
postgres-# # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
postgres-# # replication privilege.
postgres-# local   replication     all                                     peer
postgres-# host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
postgres-# host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Then restarted the service:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

**The problem:**

```
michael@michael-HP:~$ psql -U admin -W
Password for user admin: 
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "admin"
```

Could you help me understand why my md5 settings doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [manual page for `psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) states:

> If you omit the host name, psql will connect via a Unix-domain socket to a server on the local host, or via TCP/IP to localhost on machines that don't have Unix-domain sockets.

So if your server is listening on a domain socket as well as over TCP/IP, the connection you are making will be of type `local` as explained on [the `pg_hba.conf` manual page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Consequently, it will match this line:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

This will attempt to use ["peer authentication", as described here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#auth-peer).

You should either:

- Change that line to require `md5` authentication for local (domain-socket) connections.
- Specify the hostname in your `psql` command with `-h 127.0.0.1`/`--host 127.0.0.1` to force use of TCP/IP.
- Disable Unix domain sockets completely, by setting `unix_socket_directories` to an empty string as [described in the configuration section of the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html).

Comment: And is it possible to user non-peer authentication for local (domain socket) connections? I do want to use sockets instead of localhost for local connections, however I need to login as more than one user, which means I have to use other auth methods, like password or md5. However, I don't want to lose the passwordless login in case the client username does match the DB username. So basically I want something like the fallback mechanism in SSH, where in case an auth method fails, it tries the next one, until all auth methods are exhausted. Is this possible in Postgres?

Comment: @Mike Hi! For "non-peer authentication", as this answer says, you can set it to whatever auth method you choose. The part about having a fallback mechanism sounds like a completely new question. As described on the [tour], this site doesn't work like a traditional forum - it tries to keep each page strictly focussed on one question and its answers - so you should click on "Ask a Question", and include link to here if appropriate. Do check the Postgres manual first, though, starting with the links in this answer; it's generally quite well-written and comprehensive.

Comment: I get your point, but I think it's not that much of a far fetch that you want to have password auth (which is what the original poster wanted) over socket **in addition** to peer auth (which is what he actually got). And yes, I had already read the docs in the `pg_hba.conf` file itself before posting, but it doesn't say anything about fallback. In the online docs however, it says `There is no “fall-through” or “backup”: if one record is chosen and the authentication fails, subsequent records are not considered`. This perry much limits you to just 1 user if you want to user peer auth.

Comment: @Mike I didn't say the question was _unreasonable_, just that it deserved to be on its own page. I don't know the answer, and nobody else will see your comment here, whereas if you post a new question, it will show up in lists as unanswered and somebody might help. I'm curious myself, so I would happily upvote it if you wrote it clearly. (Although if that manual page you quoted is correct, the answer may simply be "sorry, that's not possible right now".)